# Javascript: MutationObserver Doesn't show me the changed Nodes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

The `MutationObserver` is a simple API that allows me to monitor DOM changes. I'm using it in a chrome-extension I want to know when certain elements on a webpage are added. and using the `childList` option which is supposed to tell me when the specified target adds new nodes.

From Mozilla Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserverInit/childList

> By setting childList to true, your callback will be invoked any time nodes are added to or removed from the DOM node or nodes being watched.

but on the callback the `change.addedNodes` and `change.removedNodes` is false. even though printing the targets' `childNodes.length` shows that the number of children is actuall changing

```js
let content_box = document.querySelector('div#content-box');    // target to monitor

// create observer with callback
let observer = new MutationObserver( (mutations, observer) => {

    mutations.forEach( change => {
            console.log(`Added:  ${change.addedNodes==true}`)    // no added nodes   (there should be)
            console.log(`Removed ${change.removedNodes==true}`)  // no removed nodes (which is fine)
            console.log(change.target)                           // I've confirmed the target is the correct one
            console.log(change.target.childNodes.length)         // after multiple callbacks the length of children is actually increasing 
    })

})


observer.observe(content_box, {
    childList: true,     // monitoring for childList changes
    attributes: false,
    subtree: false,
})
```

Comment: `.addedNodes` and `.removedNodes` are `NodeList`s. Why do you compare them to `true` (which will evaluate to `false`)? -> `change.addedNodes.length > 0`

Comment: @Andreas Just to see if they are there. Mozilla says they will be false or null or something if they are no add/removed nodes.

Comment: `change` is a [`MutationRecord`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord), and the mentioned properties (`.addedNodes`, `.removedNodes`) are `NodeList`s as you can see on the documentation about [`MutationRecord`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationRecord)s

Comment: @Andreas.. Ahh I see the problem. I think I just assumed that it would evaluate to `false` if there was nothing inside and true if there was something like and array would right? But I'm curious. why wouldn't the `NodeList` be falsy if it had nothing inisde and `true` if it did? I use other languages but I use javascript sometimes so I'm not that confident in the workings of it.

Comment: An object will always be truthy, regardless of its content. But comparing object with a boolean also won't ever be `true` -> [7.2.14 Abstract Equality Comparison](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-abstract-equality-comparison)

Comment: @Andreas so It's using number 10 then 12 to do `x == !ToNumber(y)`? And this results in false always if y is an object that's defined??

Comment: If I got this right... 10 -> 12, `ToPrimitive(x)` -> `OrdinaryToPrimitive(x, "number")` -> `x.valueOf()` (returns `x` (`this`)) -> `x.toString()` (returns `[object Object]`). So we now have `"[object Object]" == 0`, and `ToNumber("[object Object]")` returns `1` -> `1 == 0` -> `false` ([test case](https://jsfiddle.net/kqzv9be5/) for `x.valueOf()` and `x.toString()`)

Comment: Thanks @Andreas... I'll have a look at this.

Answer (score 0):

You wanna check whether the property `addedNodes` is in the object of `change`. so `console.log("addedNodes" in change)` to get a true result.

```
let content_box = document.querySelector('div#content-box');    // target to monitor

// create observer with callback
let observer = new MutationObserver( (mutations, observer) => {

    mutations.forEach( change => {

            console.log(`Added:  ${"addedNodes" in change}`)    // no added nodes   (there should be)

            console.log(`Removed ${"removedNodes" in change}`) // no removed nodes (which is fine)
            console.log(change.target)                           // I've confirmed the target is the correct one
            console.log(change.target.childNodes.length)         // after multiple callbacks the length of children is actually increasing 
    })

})


observer.observe(content_box, {
    childList: true,     // monitoring for childList changes
    attributes: false,
    subtree: false,
})
```